# UWP nested RelativePanel app crash pointing to global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, uwp-xaml, winui

I am trying to build an UWP app using nested RelativePanel layout components as part of a DataTemplate used for a ListView:

```xml
               <ListView x:Name="Listtest" Grid.Row="1"
                          SelectionMode="Single"
                          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">

                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>

                        <DataTemplate>
                            <RelativePanel>

                                <Grid RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True" x:Name="gridVoto">
                                    <Ellipse x:Name="Ellipse"
                                             Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                             Width="42"
                                             Height="42"
                                             Margin="2"
                                             Fill="{Binding decimalValue, Converter={StaticResource GradeToColorConverter}}"

                                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                             HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                        <!-- ="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumBrush}" -->
                                    </Ellipse>
                                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                               Text="{Binding displayValue}" FontSize="14" Foreground="#FFFFFF" />

                                </Grid>

                                <RelativePanel >
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="textMateria" TextWrapping="Wrap" RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True"
                                           MaxWidth="500"
                                           Text="{Binding subjectDesc}"

                                           Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"
                                           Margin="12,6,0,0" />

                                <TextBlock RelativePanel.Below="textMateria" RelativePanel.RightOf="gridVoto"
                                           TextWrapping="Wrap"

                                           Text="{Binding notesForFamily}"

                                           Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"
                                           Margin="12,0,0,6" />

                                <TextBlock RelativePanel.RightOf="textMateria" x:Name="dataVoto"
                                           Text="{Binding evtDate}"

                                           Foreground="LightGray"
                                           Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"
                                           Margin="12,6,0,0" />

                                <TextBlock RelativePanel.RightOf="dataVoto"
                                           Text="{Binding componentDesc}"


                                           Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"
                                           Foreground="LightGray"
                                           Margin="12,6,0,0" />

                                </RelativePanel>



                            </RelativePanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

When I run the app in Visual Studio it crashes without any clear exception error, but a line of code highlighted: `global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();`.

I tried using other layout components like Grid or StackPanel as child of the main RelativePanel, they work but they don't suit my needs like RelativePanel would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your behavior is the second TextBlock in the nested RelativePanel. You are setting the `RelativePanel.RightOf` to **gridVoto**. The **gridVoto** is the Grid control that out of the **main RelativePanel**, not the nested RelativePanel. So the XAML compiler can't find this element in the child elments of nested RelativePanel

```
  <TextBlock RelativePanel.Below="textMateria" RelativePanel.RightOf="gridVoto"
                                       TextWrapping="Wrap"

                                       Text="{Binding notesForFamily}"

                                       Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"
                                       Margin="12,0,0,6" />
```

Please just remove `RelativePanel.RightOf="gridVoto"` in the code. If you want put that TextBlock in the right of the Grid, you should place it in the **main RelativePanel** but out of the nested RelativePanel.